# nginx case insensitive URL redirection

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

I want to do case insensitive URL redirection in [nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx).
Below is my code.

```
location ~* WapsiteDataFetch{
      rewrite  WapsiteDataFetch(.*) http://images.xample.com/xyz/images$1 permanent;
    }
```

In the above case,

`www.example.com/WapsiteDataFetch` is redirected properly to `http://images.xample.com/xyz/images`.
However, the URL `"www.example.com/WAPSITEDATAFETCH"` is not redirected properly.

Even if I *change* a single character, it is giving a 404 error.

I have tried many blog posts and have seen many post from Stack Overflow and many of them have suggested "~*", but in my case it was not helping me.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587354/how-to-implement-nginx-case-insensitive-directory-location-redirection-301

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `(?i)` to match case-insensitively - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Location block is not necessary. Try this.

```
rewrite (?i)^/WapsiteDataFetch(.*) http://images.xample.com/xyz/images$1 permanent;
```

Comment: What do I do if there are queries in front of the url such as www.example.com/WapsiteDataFetch?q=123 etc..How should i implement this

Comment: Remove the `?` after `/images$1` to have request args appended.

Comment: It did not work..Any other suggestion you can give me.

Comment: What is the use of proxy in the nginx.conf file

Comment: I've updated the code. Does it work for you? Proxy allows passing requests to another server. - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: @hongtat..Thanks a lot for help..The above helped me.It saved a lot of my time..Thanks again

Comment: can u please come in chat..I have an issue

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using the regular expression engine twice, by doing the capturing inside the location block:

```
location ~* WapsiteDataFetch(.*) {
  return 301 http://images.xample.com/xyz/images$1;
}
```