# How to implement Nginx case-insensitive directory-location redirection 301

Tags: nginx

I want to *http://example.com/SomeThing* redirect to *http://example.com/something*

**`something`** is nginx location (`/something`) directory

**Please suggest how to implement case insensitive directory location redirection**

Answer (score 21):

I'm assuming that http://example.com/something would not be redirected. So use a prefix location for the case sensitive match with the `^~` modifier to skip checking regular expressions:

```
location ^~ /something {
    return 200 "case sensitive something match
";
}
```

Now add the case insensitive regular expression location for the redirect:

```
location ~* ^/something {
    return 301 $scheme://$host/something;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the last bit with the caret.  It was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Generally, this is a bad solution, because you hardcode `something`

Answer (score 15):

From [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching).

So `~*` in location must be used for case insensitive matching.

```
location ~* /something/ {
    # your code here
}
```

Comment: It's no longer a **pre**fix string if you use a regex. Make sure you do `location ~* ^/something/ ` to match only from the beginning.