# nginx case insensitive equals operator

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to manually redirect a couple of links from my old blog to my new blog like this:

```
location = /blog-article-url {
    return 301 https://blog.example.com/blog-article-url
}
```

And this works when i visit `https://www.example.com/blog-article-url`, i get properly redirected. However it IS case sensitive, if i visit `https://www.example.com/BLOG-ARTICLE-URL` it will NOT work.

What should i replace the `=` sign in the nginx config block to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement Nginx case-insensitive directory-location redirection 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587354/how-to-implement-nginx-case-insensitive-directory-location-redirection-301)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a case insensitive `location` block with *regular expressions*.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/blog-article-url$ { ... }
```

Note that the evaluation order of *regular expression* locations is significant - so you may need to move this `location` block towards the top of your `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.